# How Can I Code a Map Searching Operation By Using Stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to search something into a map and I wanted to do that with streams but I could not figure out how to do. Could anyone help please?

The old fashioned code is like this:

```
String softwareIp = "1.1.1.1";
String softwareName = "Soft"

Map<String, Object> mymap; // {"1.1.1.1-12": Obj, "1.1.1.1-13":Obj, "1.1.1.2-3:Obj...etc}

Obj object = null;
for (Map.Entry entry : mymap) {
    if (entry.getKey().toString().contains(softwareIP)) {
        if (entry.getValue().getName().contains(softwareName)) {
            object = entry.getValue();
        }
    }
}
```

The stream code I tried to write:

```
Obj object = mymap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> (e.getKey().toString().contains(softwareIP) &&
        e.getValue().contains(softwareName)))
    .map(mymap::get)
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);
```

Where is the problem in the stream code? What should I change? I returns null.

Comment: Neither of your examples compile. Please create a minimal reproducible example of your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The things that don’t work, are entirely unrelated to the Stream API. For some reason, you changed `entry.getValue().getName().contains(softwareName)` to `e.getValue().contains(softwareName))` (removed the `getName()` call) and the subsequent `getValue()` call on the `Map.Entry` instance to an attempt to call `get` on `myMap`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Object object = mymap.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getKey().contains(softwareIp)
                        && ((REFERENCE_CLASS) e.getValue()).getName().contains(softwareName))
                .findFirst()
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue) //<--- if you want value
                //.map(Map.Entry::getKey) //<--- if you want key
                .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stream solution is correct but the comparison is wrong.

Wrong: `e.getValue().contains(softwareName)`

Correct: `e.getValue().getName().contains(softwareName)`

Answer (score 0):

try this      .map(n -> n.getValue())

```
    String softwareIp = "1.1.1.1";
    String softwareName = "Soft";
    Map<String, String> mymap = new HashMap<>(); // {"1.1.1.1-12": Obj, "1.1.1.1-13":Obj, "1.1.1.2-3:Obj...etc}
    mymap.put("1.1.1.1-12", "Soft");
    String obj;
    obj = mymap.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> (e.getKey().contains(softwareIp) &&
                    e.getValue().contains(softwareName)))
            .map(n -> n.getValue())
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
    System.out.println(obj);
```

Comment: Hello @boboawoshi, welcome to SO. This solution does not fix the issue which the OP is facing. In fact, the code is syntactically incorrect. The map posted by OP is Map<String, Object> whereas yours is Map<String, String>. Would highly encourage to verify your answers before posting here. Cheers.